# What is the best practice for implementing common methods between spring rest controllers?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller

I am using spring rest controller to implement my web api, I want to put my common methods between controllers in one place so can be used in all my controllers.

If there is no way to extend  `@RestController` annotation, Is it a good practice to write controller common methods in a parent Class `BaseController` and extend all my controllers from it ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong to have parent controller with common methods until these methods are really belong to controller, and not just some Utils that should be moved to special class.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your [own stereotype/annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/spring-annotation-programming-model) but it would clearly be an overhead if you want only add some common methods to the controllers.  Besides, you will make your code less "Spring standard". I don't think that you want that.

> Is it a good practice to write controller common methods in a parent
>   Class BaseController and extend all my controllers from it ?

I don't think that it is a bad practice but here some scenarios where I don't want to use class inheriting for controllers :

- The common code looks like logic while controllers should not perform logic but delegate. If these make too much things, introduce a service class and delegate to it.
- if controllers don't share a set of common fields/dependencies/initializations, using a dependency class that provides the common methods would be probably clearer/simplest. Creating a hierarchy of classes to avoid declaring a common field seems too much and a subclassing abuse.
- you should favor Spring AOP and ControllerAdvice for common processing in controllers for pre/pro/processing and exception handling.

If you don't fall into these cases, yes an abstract class for your controllers looks a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you're looking for is a [service layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_layer). It can be used to store all of your business logic and common methods you might need. You extract them and inject the service object into your controller. From there you simply call your methods from the service layer and do not pollute your controller. It's considered a good practice to do so, from my experience.

Another thing you could do for methods that can be used for different kinds of controllers that have nothing in common is, as you said, can be extracted to a Utility class. You can fill this class with static methods you can use across your application.

Comment: Yes the service layer is the place for business logic but what I am looking for is:  for example,  custom handlers for the request params or some utility functions for controllers,  these methods are used in all my controllers

Comment: For utility functions I would suggest extracting them to a utility class full of static methods which just complete any action you need. However, I'm not experienced enough to say with certainty that this is best practice. It is, however, to my understanding, not frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

My controllers require common functionality like 
-inspecting parameters on incoming requests
and 
-including headers in outgoing response.

In order to avoid boilerplate of parent/child controllers invoking each other, I took advantage of spring annotations/hooks.

To parse and validate request parameters I went the route of 
a controller advice class and annotating a method therein with @ModelAttribute 
-which spring calls before the route methods 
and 
-which you can use to make objects available in the model.

To include headers in all responses I went the route of extending ResponseBodyAdvice where using custom annotations, you can the controller mapping method to indicate to the controller advice whether it should be invoked for that response.

The weak point here for me is communicating from controller to the advice for the response.
I went the route of the custom-annotated controller mapping method setting an attribute in the request for later use in the response advice (and documenting that annotated methods are expected to do so.)